# Python Scipy How to traverse upper/lower trianglar portion non-zeros from csr_matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a very sparse matrix(similarity matrix) with dimensions 300k * 300k. In order to find out the relatively greater similarities between users, I only need upper/lower triangular portion of the matrix. So, how to get the coordinates of users with value larger than a threshold in an efficient way? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
sparse.triu(M)
```

If `M` is

```
In [819]: M.A
Out[819]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)

In [820]: sparse.triu(M).A
Out[820]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 4, 5],
       [0, 0, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

You may need to construct a new sparse matrix, with just nonzeros above the threshold.

```
In [826]: sparse.triu(M>2).A
Out[826]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [827]: sparse.triu(M>2).nonzero()
Out[827]: (array([1, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([1, 2, 2], dtype=int32))
```

Here's the code for `triu`:

```
def triu(A, k=0, format=None):
    A = coo_matrix(A, copy=False)
    mask = A.row + k <= A.col
    row = A.row[mask]
    col = A.col[mask]
    data = A.data[mask]
    return coo_matrix((data,(row,col)), shape=A.shape).asformat(format)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's pretty straight forward.